# How to manipulate width of multiple images in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have multiple images and i wnat to place all of them in a single line.How should i manipulate the width of images such that the sum of width of al images does not exceed the browser's width.??

Comment: Please specify a library you are using (mootools,jquery,dojo etc) otherwise it is a pain in the $#$% to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have variable width images you could go with something like this:

```
/**
*@param contId {string} id of the container element
*/
var imgResize = function(contId) {
    var imgs = [], totalWidth = 0, ratio = 0, containerWidth = 0;
    var cont = document.getElementById(contId);
    var child = cont.firstChild;
    while(child.nextSibling){
        if(child.tagName && child.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'IMG'){ 
            var imgW = child.clientWidth;
            imgs.push({node: child, width: imgW});
            totalWidth += imgW;
        }
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
    ratio =  cont.clientWidth / totalWidth;

    imgs.forEach(function(img){
        var cWidth = Math.floor(ratio*img.width);
        img.node.style.cssText='width:'+cWidth+'px';
    });
};

/**
* Fire it on window resizes, ooohh shiny
*/
window.onresize=function(){imgResize('container');};
```

Keep in mind that you should probably do something like

```
img{border:0px;display:block;float:right;}
.imgContainer{font-size:0px;padding:0px;width:100%;/*for example*/}
```

Getting this to work in less than modern browsers is left as an exercise to the reader. 
And yes, using a framework is a fine idea, I would recommend YUI, so good that even Russians have been known to use it.

Comment: This is very very close to a perfect solution. The only thing I would suggest is changing the while condition to "while (child)". As currently written, it won't act on the last image.

Answer (score 0):

```
var width = (window.width / numImages) - margin;
```

Comment: what is padding.?? also the images are asymmetric...so if asssign the width of all the images to (window.width)/numImages.Some images get cut off...

Comment: Oops. I didn't figure you'd have different widths. Silly me. Padding should actually be 'margin'.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to target them all at the same time give them all the same class or go from a containing id and get them by node name. After targeting them get their widths.

To get the widths into variables with jquery:

```
var $allImages = $('img.myImages');//all images need the same class

var allImagesW = $allImages.width() * $allImages.length;//you might want to use .outerWidth() to account for borders and padding, and .outerWidth(true) to include margins.

var windowW = $(window).width();
```

Comment: I am not using jquery...i am using pure javascript